# How to unindex lists in Objectify?

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing, entity, objectify

Why is it not possible to unindex a list of an objectify entity?

To demonstrate the problem I made a simple example project.

I used the entity

```
@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id String id;
    @Unindex List<Passenger>  passengers;
}
```

an the object

```
public class Passenger {
    String name;
}
```

and saved it using this simple method.

```
public class CarFactory {

    public void writeCarEntity() {
        Car car = new Car();
        car.setId("myCar");

        List<Passenger> passengers = new LinkedList<Passenger>();

        Passenger carl = new Passenger();    
        carl.setName("Carl");

        Passenger pete = new Passenger();
        pete.setName("Pete");

        Passenger jeff = new Passenger();
        jeff.setName("Jeff");

        passengers.add(carl);
        passengers.add(pete);
        passengers.add(jeff);

        car.setPassengers(passengers);

        ObjectifyService.register(car.getClass());
        ObjectifyService.ofy().save().entity(car).now();
    }
}
```

Looking up the entity in the datastore you get this information:

[image: This is a screenshot from the Datastore]

Although the passengers field has the annotation `@Unindex` it will be indexed, as one can see in the google "Datastore". Why does the annotation `@Unindex` has no effect in this example???

Comment: can you please post the screenshot from your datastore

Comment: @MichaelMeyer of course, I added it to the original post.....

Comment: how did you save the entities? with objectify or did you use the class Entity?

Comment: @MichaelMeyer I added the method I use to save the entity...

Comment: not adding @Index should do it and also check your datastore-indexes.xml if it was not explicitly enforced there

Comment: @TheophilusOmoregbee but I never set "@Index" somewhere, see my example. Furthermore, I explicitly set "@Unindex" (which is default anyway).

Comment: what about your datastore-indexes.xml did u check it too, or go online on your cloud console check  datastore and indexes and did you say the embedded class is not an entity too

Comment: In my WEB-INF folder I don't have a file called "datastore-indexes.xml", in my cloud console the indexes (console.cloud.google.com/datastore/indexes) says: "This application doesn't have any composite indexes.....". I also tried to set "@Unindex" at the passenger class -> same phenomena. Still indexed in the datastore. (btw. passenger is not embedded)

Comment: this is serious

Comment: @MiraStinktshir since passenger is not an embedded object instead an entity use (without @Index)
List<Ref<Passenger>> passengers= new ArrayList<>();

then the getter use 
 public List<Passenger> getPassengers() {
        return new ArrayList<>(ofy().load().refs(passengers).values());
    }

Comment: I am not lucky with this workaround. There must be a more sophisticated solution for this problem. I can't be the only one who has a list of (not embedded) objects in an entity and don't want them to be indexed.

Comment: @MiraStinktshir but the normal Ref worked , try it out should work , if it works let me know, because thats what i use here i use REFs instead for embedded entities

Answer (score 1):

This is unrelated to Objectify and appears to be some new quirk of the datastore. It might just be a display glitch in the UI. Is it causing problems?

With the code you posted, Objectify will call `Entity.saveUnindexedProperty()` on the `passengers` field (even without the `@Unindex` annotation). But even if Objectify tried to index it, historically you can't index embedded objects, so it's unclear what it means to index a list of them. Maybe Google is rolling out some new behavior and they haven't got the GUI working correctly yet? Or maybe there is a bug in their save behavior?

If you want to be a good citizen, create a simple test case with the low level API (an `Entity` that contains a property of type `List<EmbeddedEntity>`), verify that this same behavior occurs, and file a bug in the GAE issue tracker.

Comment: In my case, *Passenger* is not an embedded object.

Comment: Then you must be using code totally different from what you posted. If you have a field of type `List<Passenger>`, then you have a list of embedded objects.

Comment: ohh sorry I mixed up the terms *embedded* and *nested*. So **Passengers** is embedded but not nested.

Comment: What do you mean by "nested"? That isn't a term that exists in the Objectify or GAE documentation.